# sed - conditional replacement of similar string patterns

Tags: sed

I try to replace/append strings in text files with `sed`.
Another string ("green") needs to be matched before a replacement is allowed.

The strings are very similar:

```
apple >> apple_tree
apple X1 >> apple_tree
appleX1 >> apple_tree
```

This code works if the condition is not taken into account and the first occurrence of one of the strings should be replaced:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '0,/apple|apple X1|appleX1/{s/apple|apple X1|appleX1/apple_tree/}' {} +
```

This code can not be executed (prompt is waiting)

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/green/,// /apple|apple A0|appleA0/{s/apple|apple A0|appleA0/apple_tree/}' {} +
```

Although this one works without alternative patterns:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i '/green/,// s/apple/apple_tree/' {} +
```

Unfortunately, using word border indicators like \<apple\> does not work either.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04. The solution is not restricted to `sed`.

Thank you.

Edit:

Input:

```
orange
pear
kiwi
apple X1
mango
banana
apple

green

orange
pear
kiwi
apple X1
mango
appleX1
banana
apple
```

```
Code execution
```

Desired output:

```
orange
pear
kiwi
apple X1
mango
banana
apple

green

orange
pear
kiwi
apple_tree
mango
apple_tree
banana
apple_tree
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
sed -i -e '/green/,$s/apple\( A0\|A0\|\)/apple_tree/'
```

Check out https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html https://regexcrossword.com/